# Laravel Identity User without revealing ID to the user

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-echo

In laravel I've set a `privatechannel` for websocket broadcasting.

The channel is this:

```
Broadcast::channel('user.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

So in this case I am revealing the user's ID to them as a part of the authentication process.

Does Laravel have any other unique user identifier I could use that does not leak user count info to the user?

For example:

```
Broadcast::channel('user.{token}', function ($user, $token) {
    return $user->some_unique_token === $token;
});
```

Or should I just use something like https://hashids.org/php/ to obfuscate the user ID?  (not sure if Laravel ships with something like this?)

Comment: You could store a unique identifier token along with the ID and show that instead, but what's the problem with showing them their ID?

Comment: I don't like to reveal how many users I have

Comment: The ID is not necessarily reflecting that, the user with ID 10 does not know how many users has been registered since. Yes, you can just create a new user and check the ID of that,  but what's the big issue - I fail to see the problem? If it really is a major issue, then just generate a UUID for the user and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just created a simple hash method for the user model and then used this instead of the ID to validate the user.

This was the method added to user model:

```
public function hash(){
    return hash('sha256',$this->id.env('APP_KEY'));
}
```

Then broadcast channel goes like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('user.{hash}', function ($user, $hash) {
    return $user->hash() === $hash;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to generate unique user id (uuid) and do all stuff with uuid make another column of uuid into users table  `Str::uuid();` this will not reveal the user id [Laravel Str Helper for uuid](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-uuid)

Answer (score 0):

the best way for that is using some two-way hash algorithm like hashids
even in JWT for preventing user_id being revealed using hashids is one of the best ways